# How to reset or rebuild application search database in ios?

Tags: ios, search, firefox

I am having a strange problem on ios. When i search for any app by typing its name in the search screen, the corresponding app shows up, WITH THE EXCEPTION, of firefox for ios. Its odd to me that my firefox app is completely ommitred from search results and I have to manually find the app each time I want to use it. Is there a way to rebuild the app search database in ios?

Comment: Is Firefox's `Siri & Search` setting turned on?

Comment: No it is not. That was the problem. I dont remember turning it off, but either way, problem solved. Thankyou @fsb

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the app is included in Siri's search index.

To do that on iOS 12, go to `Settings -> Siri & Search`.

Scroll down to find the app.  Turn on the switch.  Wait a few min then try searching for the app again.

[image]

Comment: Both answers did it. Thank you! How do i mark as solved?

Comment: I'm glad it worked (although, the first one was a comment and not an answer :-) ).  You can see [this page to learn how to accept an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), it's pretty simple and quick.